# log loss computed manually diverging from the cross_validation_score method from scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have a question about how the `cross_val_score()` from the Scikit-Learn works. I tried divide the dataset in 10 folds with `Kfold()` and compute the log loss of both training and validation sets for each fold. However I got different answers using the `cross_validation_score`, setting the parameter `scoring = 'neg_log_loss'`.

`X` and `y` are arrays of shape `(1800, 12)` and `(1800, 1)`, respectively.

```
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10)
train_loss = []
val_loss = []

for train_index, val_index in kfold.split(X, y):
    
    clf_logreg = LogisticRegression()
    
    # 
    X_train, X_val = X[train_index], X[val_index]
    y_train, y_val = y[train_index], y[val_index]
    
    clf_logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    y_train_pred = clf_logreg.predict(X_train)
    y_val_pred = clf_logreg.predict(X_val)
    
    train_loss.append(log_loss(y_train, y_train_pred))
    val_loss.append(log_loss(y_val, y_val_pred))    
    
clf_logreg.fit(X,y)
y_error = cross_val_score(clf_logreg, X, y, cv=kfold, scoring='neg_log_loss')

print("cross_val log_loss: ", -y_error)
print("\ntrain_loss: ", train_loss)
print("\nval_loss: ", val_loss)
```

The answers I got:

```
cross_val log_loss:  [0.18546779 0.18002459 0.21591202 0.15872213 0.22852112 0.18766844
 0.28641203 0.14923009 0.21446935 0.20373971]

train_loss:  [2.79298449379999, 2.7290223160363962, 2.558457002245472, 2.835624958485065, 2.5797806896386337, 2.622420660745048, 2.5797797024813125, 2.6224201671663874, 2.5797782217453302, 2.6863818513513213]

val_loss:  [1.9188431218680995, 2.1107385395747733, 3.645826363693089, 2.110734097366828, 3.2620355282797417, 2.686367043991502, 3.453913177154633, 2.4944849529086657, 2.8782624616981765, 2.4944938373245567]
```

Comment: log-loss needs the predicted probabilities, but the hard class predictions

Answer (score 0):

As [Ben Reiniger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10495893/ben-reiniger) noted in the comment `log_loss` expects probabilities in `y_train_pred`, `y_val_pred`. So you need to change

`clf_logreg.predict`

to:

`clf_logreg.predict_proba`

Example:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
y = y == 1
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
train_loss = []
val_loss = []

for train_index, val_index in kfold.split(X, y):

    clf_logreg = LogisticRegression()

    #
    X_train, X_val = X[train_index], X[val_index]
    y_train, y_val = y[train_index], y[val_index]

    clf_logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)

    y_train_pred = clf_logreg.predict_proba(X_train)
    y_val_pred = clf_logreg.predict_proba(X_val)

    train_loss.append(log_loss(y_train, y_train_pred))
    val_loss.append(log_loss(y_val, y_val_pred))

clf_logreg.fit(X, y)
y_error = cross_val_score(clf_logreg, X, y, cv=kfold, scoring="neg_log_loss")

print("cross_val log_loss: ", -y_error)
print("\nval_loss: ", val_loss)
```

Results:

```
cross_val log_loss:  [0.53548503 0.54200945 0.60324094 0.64781483 0.43323992 0.37625601
 0.55101127 0.46172226 0.50216316 0.64359642]

val_loss:  [0.5354850268015129, 0.5420094471965571, 0.6032409439788419, 0.647814828089315, 0.43323991804482626, 0.3762560144867495, 0.5510112741331039, 0.46172225526408, 0.5021631570133954, 0.6435964210060579]
```